# Closing Mvvmcross tutorial with back button

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

If I run the implementation of the [tutorial](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Tutorial-Part-1) being on the MainMenuView and pressing back will exit the application, but in my app it just goes to SplashScreenView and is redirected back to MainMenuView and I cant find where in the tutorial its specified or overrided what happens when the back button is clicked

**EDIT**:
Solution found here https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Sample%20-%20Tutorial/Tutorial/Tutorial.UI.Droid/SplashScreenActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Label = "Tutorial.UI.Droid", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class SplashScreenActivity
    : MvxBaseSplashScreenActivity
{
    public SplashScreenActivity()
        : base(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        // ignored
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no hidden code for this - its just the android back stack.

Are you sure your app is actually exiting cleanly? It sounds a bit like your app is crashing and being restarted? Check the debug log to find out.

Alternatively it might also be that you have missed the nohistory flag on the splashscreen